# About the counting measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: measure-theory

Is the counting measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ (restricted to the Borel sigma algebra) a Borel measure respectivly a Radon measure?

Comment: ok lets begin, it is a Borel measure because it is restricted to the borel sigma algebra (but the measure is always $\infty$ unless for the empty set), right? And it is not a Radon measure because it is not locally finite (every open neighborhood has measure $\infty$, true? :)

Comment: It is Borel if restricted to the Borel sigma - algebra but note that all finite sets are in that sigma-algebra. The rest of what you said is correct.

Comment: I dont understand your point that all finite sets are in that sigma algebra. Every set (besides the empty set) has counting measure $\infty$, isn't it?

Comment: No...finite sets are assigned their cardinality. And finite sets are closed, hence Borel.

Comment: everthing remains the same if we look at the number of rational numbers in a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, right?